# What is the best way to do long polling in AJAX requests in JavaScript without JQuery?

Tags: javascript, ajax, long-polling

hi after searching in the net about how to use the `long polling` in `JavaScript` I ended up with three ways, they are mentioned [here](https://gist.github.com/jhbsk/4353139) briefly,but they are implemented using JQuery. I am confused which one to use in case that the AJAX request that I send to the server is asynchronous GET request ,and I don't know how many time it could take.

here is an example AJAX request:

```
function asynchGETRequest(method,url){
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log("ok");
    }
    };
    xhttp.open(method, url, true);
    xhttp.send();
    return (xhttp.responseText);
}


var clientFunctions={
     getAnswers : function(callback){
        var res=asynchGETRequest("GET", "http://localhost:9000/answers");
        callback(JSON.stringify(res));
     }
}

 clientFunctions.getAnswers (function(){
       //do some code here after the ajax request is ended
 });
```

can some one guide me please?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the solution **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#Example_using_a_timeout)**

```
function loadFile(sUrl, timeout, callback){

    var args = arguments.slice(3);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.ontimeout = function () {
        console.error("The request for " + url + " timed out.");
    };
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                callback.apply(xhr, args);
            } else {
                console.error(xhr.statusText);
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.timeout = timeout;
    xhr.send(null);
}
```